# How to access the below object parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
output = "{\"response\":200,\"message\":\"Id: 123 updated successfully\"}{\"response\":403,\"message\":\"Receipt with Id: 124 not updated\"}"
```

How to access the response on the above output? Unable to convert to json due to invalid format

Comment: Unable to convert to json due to invalid format. need suggestions on retrieving the above values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you have is almost valid, you could put the two objects into an array and walk through them to check for the key value 'response' and for example print the values like so:

```
output = [{"response":200,"message":"Id: 123 updated successfully"},
          {"response":403,"message":"Receipt with Id: 124 not updated"}];
for(let i=0; i<output.length; i++){
  if(output[i].hasOwnProperty('response')){
      console.log(output[i]['response']);
   }
 }
```

Output:

```
200
403
```

Please note the '[]' brackets put around the response objects returned to make the variable 'output' iterable.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```js
output = `{"response":200,"message":"Id: 123 updated successfully"}{"response":403,"message":"Receipt with Id: 124 not updated"}`
output = output.replaceAll("}", "},");
output = output.substring(0, output.length - 1);
output = "[" + output  + "]"

console.log(output)
console.log(JSON.parse(output) )
```